# Do Vikings in ground form benefit from air or ground attack upgrades?

Tags: starcraft-2

When you land Vikings, do their attacks benefit from Vehicle Weapons or Ship Weapons upgrades?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Vikings benefit from upgrading ship weapons even when they have landed.

I made this video to show it:

Answer (score 14):

Vikings in Assault Mode (ground mode) still benefit from **Ship Weapons** upgrades.

Twin Gatling Cannon is upgraded by `+1` for each level in Ship Weapons.

[Ship Weapons](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Ship_Weapons) upgrades the attack of Starport units,

> Increase the damage of Terran Air units.

Also on the [Liquipedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Viking#Abilities) article for Viking,

> Note that the Viking always benefits from Ship Weapons upgrade, even in Assault Mode.

Also on [Starcraft Wikia](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Viking#Wings_of_Liberty), the `+1` upgrade on Twin Gatling Cannon is followed by a Ship Weapons upgrade icon.

[image]

Comment: I believe the help text on Ship Weapons says that it improves the damage of units "built at the Starport" as opposed to "air units."  This may have been an attempt to be more clear about this very topic.

Answer (score 9):

From [Liquipedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Viking):

> Note that the Viking always benefits from Ship Weapons upgrade, even in Assault Mode.

Comment: Haha we pulled the same quote at the same time

Comment: @BBz yep, happens quite often with easy answers like this